# Astro initialize project Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty

Tags: npm, command-line-interface, npm-install, astrojs

it was okay 2 days ago, i installed almost anything on brew, whenever i do `create astro` it sent me the same error in any package manager

```
node:fs:1213
  return handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
         ^

Error: ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir 'p22'
    at Object.rmdirSync (node:fs:1213:10)
    at copyTemplate (file:///Users/rezaarya4/.npm/_npx/a3f2c23699a1336a/node_modules/create-astro/dist/index.js:767:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errno: -66,
  syscall: 'rmdir',
  code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
  path: 'p22'
}
```

for now i did complete renstall node from brew, deleting all node modules in all package manager folders, using nvm, and restarting my mac, i'm afraid my Mac one's causing it, or there's a corrupt node module causing this? sorry i'm new to this

Comment: Are you doing the full command `npm create astro@latest`?

Comment: @BryceRussell yes, most of the time

Answer (score 0):

I also have this error regularly. Often on the .astro directory it creates.

It is usually enough to restart the "npm run build" once or twice and it's ok...
All this seems very fragile